# C++ templates: How to conditionally compile different code based on data type?

Tags: c++, templates

Here's a small example that illustrates the essence of my question:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
typedef char achar_t ;

template < class T > class STRING
{
   public:
     T *    memory   ;
     int    size     ;
     int    capacity ;
   public:
     STRING() {
        size     =   0 ;
        capacity = 128 ;
        memory   = ( T *) malloc( capacity * sizeof(T) ) ;
     }
     const STRING& operator=( T * buf) {
         if ( typeid(T) == typeid(char) )
            strcpy( memory, buf ) ;
         else
            wcscpy( memory, buf ) ;
        return *this ;
     }
}  ;

void main()
{
  STRING<achar_t> a ;
  STRING<wchar_t> w ;
  a =  "a_test" ;
  w = L"w_test" ;
 cout << " a = " << a.memory << endl ;
 cout << " w = " << w.memory << endl ;
}
```

Can some one please help me compile the above? That is somehow compile either with strcpy() or wcscpy() based on the type of the object i am using.

thank you

Comment: Also, `partial template specialization`.

Comment: That code formatting makes my head hurt.

Comment: An answer to your question will be the source of your next question: How do I pick `cout`/`wcout` based on some predicate?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`std::char_traits<CharT>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits).

You can replace `strcpy()` and `wcscpy()` by combining the static methods [`std::char_traits::length()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/length) and [`std::char_traits::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits/copy). This will also make your code more generic because `std::char_traits` has specializations for `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

```
 STRING& operator=( T const * buf) {
    // TODO: Make sure that buffer size for 'memory' is large enough.
    //       You propably also want to assign the 'size' member.        

    auto len = std::char_traits< T >::length( buf );
    std::char_traits< T >::copy( memory, buf, len );

    return *this ;
 }
```

**Side notes:**

- I changed the type of parameter `buf` to `T const*` because it is not legal to assign a string literal to a pointer that points to non-const data. We only need read access to the data pointed to by `buf`.
- I changed the return type to `STRING&` because that's the way how the [assignment operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) usually is declared. The method must be non-const so there is no point in restricting the return type to a constant reference.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using C++17, you can use `if constexpr` also:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<char, T>::value)
   strcpy( memory, buf );
else
   wcscpy( memory, buf );
```

The branch that fails the condition will not be compiled for the given template instantiation.

Comment: Well, this is what I am after. Thank you!. The problem now is my compiler... I use MS Visual Studio 2015....

Comment: Even VS2017 (update 2) doesn't have it. I am having VS2017 update 3 preview installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template specialization.

```
template<typename T>
class STRING {
public:
 T *    memory   ;
 int    size     ;
 int    capacity ;
public:
 STRING() {
    size     =   0 ;
    capacity = 128 ;
    memory   = ( T *) malloc( capacity * sizeof(T) ) ;
 }
STRING const & operator=(T * buf);
};
```

And you define a specialization for the type you want

```
template<> STRING<achar_t> const & STRING<achar_t>::operator=(achar_t * buf)
{
    strcpy(memory, buf );
    return *this;
}

template<> STRING<wchar_t> const & STRING<wchar_t>::operator=(wchar_t * buf)
{
    wcscpy( memory, buf );
    return *this;
}
```

I didn't test this code but you can find more information here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization

Comment: This solves the problem but splits the code... the idea of using template is gone...

Comment: @GeorgeT.: The idea of templates is not, that the template **implementation** is shared. The idea of templates is, that client code does not need to repeat itself. If you insist, that template implementations must share code, you were given a [solution that caters to you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44371974/1889329) as well (which apparently you didn't like as much as the other crude attempts).